# Placing .htaccess in a folder - does it apply site-wide or just to that folder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I could not find a clear answer to my question.

In my public_html folder I have a subfolder called my_subfolder.

In my_subfolder I put a .htaccess file that contains this rule:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Does the rule apply only to files in my_subfolder, or site-wide?

Thanks!

Comment: RTFM: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/configuring.html#htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It applies to everything inside the subfolder, including its children folders and files.

If you look at the [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html#what), they state that:

> .htaccess files (or "distributed configuration files") provide a way to make configuration changes on a per-directory basis. A file, containing one or more configuration directives, is placed in a particular document directory, **and the directives apply to that directory, and all subdirectories thereof**